# How to cross-validate a deep learning model for highly imbalanced datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, multiclass-classification

I am working with a multi-modality classification problem (with `Keras`). I have 1000, 5000 and 10000 samples for three different classes. I would like to do a five fold cross-validation to select the best pre-trained deep learning model for deployment. I'm including class weights during model training to give more weightage for less-pronounced classes. For a given fold, I would be validating with 200, 1000 and 2000 samples from these three classes. Is accuracy a good prediction measure to be used in this case? Or do I have to measure the F1-score and Matthews correlation coefficients as well? Am I doing it right?

Comment: Using [stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accuracy is not a good indicator of success with imbalanced data. The accepted answer is correct: F1 score is commonly used. Other options include `roc_auc_score` (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html)) and `average_precision_score` (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html)), both defined through scikit-learn.

If you're using Keras, I would recommend using `class_weights` (note this will not work well if you have a multi-label problem, although there are some workarounds, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254832/keras-class-weight-in-multi-label-binary-classification)).

Answer (score 1):

You have imbalanced data set, so you should use `F1` score. Also you can use weight for rare classes, so that your cost function will be formed in a way that it cares about rare classes so much and tries to classify them correctly. You also can use confusion matrix for the details, but `F1` will suffice. And yes, use `F1` instead of precision or recall. You can also take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/26730/28175).